# Making two tables appears under each other with jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and it prints one table and I believe that it prints the other underneath it so I can't see it.

How to print them under each other?

If you want any other part of the code, tell me.

```js
function jqGrid11(data) {
    this.data = data.data;
    this.deletefunction = data.deletefunction;
    this.editfunction = data.editfunction;
    this.insertfunction = data.insertfunction;
};

jqGrid11.prototype = {
    display: function() {
        var html = [];
        var index = 0;
        html.push("<table id='table'>\n<body>");
        html.push("<div id='jqGridPager'>\n</div>");
        html.push("</body>\n</table>");
        $('body').append(html.join(""));

        $("#table").jqGrid({
            url: "index.jsp",
            datatype: "local", 
            data: this.data,
            colModel: this.getColModels(this.data[0]),
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 780,
            height: 250,
            rowNum: 20,
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
    },

    getColNames: function(data) {
        var keys = [];
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
        }

        return keys;
    },

    getColModels: function(data) {
        var colNames = this.getColNames(data);
        var colModelsArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++) {
            var str;
            str = {
                name: colNames[i],
                index: colNames[i],
            };
            colModelsArray.push(str);
        }

        return colModelsArray;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you have a body and div tag in your table?

Comment: to append the html code to

Comment: the same problem still occurs

Answer (score 0):

You have VERY invalid HTML.

Change your code to

```
html.push("<table id='table'></table>");
html.push("<div id='jqGridPager'></div>");
$('body').append(html.join(""));
```

Also I see only one table there

Comment: the same problem still occurs

Comment: i am making new object from it and enter different data

Comment: Show the HTML and CSS output if you have it. Make an examplewith working code - if the CSS is position absolute then that would be the reason